# Maximum size of xmltype column in oracle 11gr1?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Was wondering if anyone knows the max allowable size for a xmltype column in oracle 11gr1 stored as binary XML? Searched the web and developer's guide but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a [page](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html) with the datatypes defined.

It says the maximum size is 4GB .